# How to implement the nesting navigation (StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator) using react navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have module where I need to use the stack navigator in the LoginScreen however when the user successfully login drawer navigator will implement instead of stack navigator. Right now i got an error it says.

> functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

What I have on my app.js

```
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const UnauthenticatedScreen = () => {   
        <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Login" 
                    component={Login} 
                    options=
                    {{
                        headerShown: false,
                    }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Registration" 
                    component={Register} 
                    options={{
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: '#4ABDFF'
                        },
                        headerTitleStyle: {
                            color: '#fff',
                        },
                        headerTintColor:'#fff',
                    }}
                
                />

                <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Privacy" 
                    component={PrivacyPolicy} 
                    options={{
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: '#4ABDFF'
                        },
                        headerTitleStyle: {
                            color: '#fff',
                        },
                        headerTitle:'Privacy Policy',
                        headerTintColor:'#fff',
                    }}
                />

                <Stack.Screen
                    name="RegistrationSuccess"
                    component={RegistrationSuccess}
                    options=
                    {{
                        headerShown: false,
                    }}
                />
        </Stack.Navigator>

}

function AuthenticatedDriverScreen() {
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="DriverDashboard">
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="DriverDashboard"
        component={DriverDashboard}
        options={{ drawerLabel: 'Home' }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
}

function App() {
    const isLogin = false;
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
         {isLogin ? AuthenticatedDriverScreen : UnauthenticatedScreen}
        </NavigationContainer>

    )
}
  
export default App;
```

Very well appreciated your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the correct answer:
Component instead of  from render

```
<NavigationContainer>
         {isLogin ? <AuthenticatedDriverScreen/> : <UnauthenticatedScreen/>}
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the jsx but instead just outing it in the body of the function. But if you don’t want to write return manually, then use this syntax: const component = () => (jsx).

If you are lazy, just copy paste the fixed code:

```
   const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const UnauthenticatedScreen = () => (
        <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Login" 
                    component={Login} 
                    options=
                    {{
                        headerShown: false,
                    }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Registration" 
                    component={Register} 
                    options={{
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: '#4ABDFF'
                        },
                        headerTitleStyle: {
                            color: '#fff',
                        },
                        headerTintColor:'#fff',
                    }}
                
                />

                <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Privacy" 
                    component={PrivacyPolicy} 
                    options={{
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: '#4ABDFF'
                        },
                        headerTitleStyle: {
                            color: '#fff',
                        },
                        headerTitle:'Privacy Policy',
                        headerTintColor:'#fff',
                    }}
                />

                <Stack.Screen
                    name="RegistrationSuccess"
                    component={RegistrationSuccess}
                    options=
                    {{
                        headerShown: false,
                    }}
                />
        </Stack.Navigator>

)

function AuthenticatedDriverScreen() {
    return (<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="DriverDashboard">
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="DriverDashboard"
        component={DriverDashboard}
        options={{ drawerLabel: 'Home' }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>)
}

function App() {
    const isLogin = false;
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
         {isLogin ? AuthenticatedDriverScreen : UnauthenticatedScreen}
        </NavigationContainer>

    )
}
  
export default App;
```

I haven’t tested the code but it should work. If it doesn’t please say.

Comment: @DevGe does it give any info about where the error is

Answer (score 0):

try changing (I haven’t tested , please let me know the result)

```
function AuthenticatedDriverScreen() {
```

to

```
const AuthenticatedDriverScreen= () => {
```

Comment: Sorry, I just amended my answer (previously duplicated declaration)

Comment: In my understanding you would like to use normal navigation if the user has NOT logged in , but use drawer navigation if he/she has logged in. Am I correct ?

Comment: yes, your correct. if the user not logged in. user will use UnauthenticatedScreen else AuthenticatedDriverScreen

Comment: Errors gives me: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I removed your Function call. But if the error still persists, let's further check.

Comment: Great ! Have a nice day !

Comment: Thank you ken for some idea.

Comment: Just checked your profile. We are having similar skill sets. (for sure I believe PHP and react are kings).Have a wonderful Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

Create Root Stack container and Drawer Container. if you want to show Drawer in stack container give component as Drawer Container.

```
import * as React from 'react';    
import { Button,SafeAreaView, View, Platform,Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator,TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { KeyboardAccessoryNavigation } from 'react-native-keyboard-accessory';
import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/stack';


import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './src/redux/store/store';

import {appColor} from './src/helper/constants'
//screens
import {Splash} from './src/screen/Splash'
import {Login} from './src/screen/Login'
import {ForgotPassword} from './src/screen/ForgotPassword'
import {Register} from './src/screen/Register'
import {Home} from './src/screen/Home'
import {SideMenu} from './src/screen/Drawer'
import {MyRewards,SubCategorieslist} from './src/screen/MyRewards'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {

  
  const RootStack = () =>{

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator style = {{flex:1}}>

      <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={Splash}  options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      
      <Stack.Screen name ="Dashboard" component ={DrawerStack} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
     

      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }
  const DrawerStack = () =>{

    return(
    <Drawer.Navigator 
    drawerStyle={{width:300}}
    drawerType="slide"
    screenOptions={{
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: appColor,
      },
      headerShown:true,
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    }}
    drawerContent={props => <SideMenu {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  
      <Drawer.Screen name="MyRewards" component={MyRewards} options={{title:'My Rewards'}} />   
      <Drawer.Screen name="SubCategorieslist" component={SubCategorieslist} options= {({ navigation }) => ({title:'Sub-Categories',headerLeft: (props) => (<HeaderBackButton {...props} onPress={()=>{navigation.goBack(null)}}/>)})} />   
      
           
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    )

  }



  return (
    <View style = {{flex:1}}>

    <Provider store={store}>
    <NavigationContainer>
     <RootStack/>
    </NavigationContainer>
    
     </Provider>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```